# Facebook Login for Website, needs to make it open on mobile app

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to integrate a wordpress login with facebook one.

Facebook login itself it's not a problem, but if we go on the website from mobile, fb login will open a new browser window (Safari, or Chrome etc.).
Is there a way to make it open the App on the phone instead of another web page?

Thanks.

Comment: what app should it open? and what is your login code?

Comment: Facebook App. Login code is standard one provided by facebook.

Comment: why would you want to open the facebook app? i don't get it.

Comment: I've got a website, this website has a facebook login. If u are navigating on the site from a mobile phone (i.e. an Iphone) and u press "Login With Facebook", i need to make the Facebook App installed on the Iphone to open. Right now, if u click on "login with facebook" from mobile, it will open a new browser tab. Most ppl does not remember facebook login datas. That's why i need the app to open, so i can get info from there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761568/how-to-open-facebook-app-from-url-only-if-installed

Comment: That's wont answer, But it helped a bit.

Comment: you can´t "get info from there". you need to authorize users in the browser.

Comment: U know, sounds like Fb wont allow it. But kinda senseless, most ppl dont remember Fb login data's.

Comment: are you sure that most people don´t remember their own login data? that would be weird. still not sure what you want to achieve, to be honest. login data will get stored in the browser anyway, so they only need to do it once. if you want to use SSO, you have to create a native app.

Comment: are you sure that most people don´t remember their own login data?  Yes i'm sure, right now we already have Fb login on our website, but most ppl are not using it cause they usually visit site from mobile phone, and they dont remember FB access. Dont think like a 16-26 boy, think to older ppl. That's why i need to make it open on the app to handle the login.

Comment: how did you find out that they "don´t know their login data"? i know what you mean, and i usually avoid loggin in on my phone too when i hit a website with fb login, but that´s only because it´s annoying - especially with 2 step verification ;) - either way, check out my answer, what you want to achieve is only possible with a native app. you can´t just abuse the official fb app for this. you can only open it if it´s installed, but that´s about it.

Comment: Tested on ppl:D We went around to show the site and make it test to the ppl. 8/10 did not remember FB login data. Anyway i know i can make it open, but that's not enough, and making ppl download an app to login it's not fine:D

Comment: i´m afraid there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use the existing login of the installed Facebook App is to use SSO (single sign on), but you can only use it in a native App. You can open the Facebook App from a website, but it does not seem to be what you want: [how to open Facebook app from url only if installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761568/how-to-open-facebook-app-from-url-only-if-installed)

For example: https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10150318348450484/