# Facebook page opens in browser instead of mobile app

Tags: html, facebook

I have added social icons on a website and added link of the business page like following:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pagename/" target="_blank"></a>Facebook</a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/pagename" target="_blank"></a>Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/channelname" target="_blank">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the `twitter` and `youtube` links through mobile device, it opens on the respective application. But `facebook` opens on it's mobile site `m.facebook.com/pagename`.

I want to open the facebook link on it's mobile app as well if user clicks the facebook link from mobile device. Kindly, let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `fb://` instead of `https://`

Comment: By using fb:// will it work fine in desktop view? I mean will open in web facebook page ?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761568/how-to-open-facebook-app-from-url-only-if-installed

Answer (score 0):

Facebooks has a separate mobile url, it is called like this:

http://m.facebook.com/pagename/

Comment: when clicked from mobile it opens the mobile url only. But, I want it to open in fb app if is it installed on the device