# Detect whether facebook app is installed in device or not

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, facebook

I want to check whether facebook app is installed on iOS or Andriod device using javascript.

If it is installed then open facebook page in app else open it in browser.

Anyone knows how to check it in javascript?

Thank you,
Trupti

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675535/how-to-launch-apps-facebook-twitter-etc-from-mobile-browser-but-fall-back-to-h

Comment: I have checked the link posted in question's comment above. The js code provided in that post is not detecting whether FB app is installed or not. It is simply redirecting to fb:// page or http://facebook.com.

Comment: Does anyone know, how to do it?