# Trying to Launch App from Mobile website, if App does not exists continue on mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<a class="intent" href="http://mymobilewebsite"  data-scheme="myApp://"></a>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function () {

            goToUri($("a.intent").data('scheme'), $("a.intent").attr('href'));
            event.preventDefault();

            function goToUri(uri, href) {
                var start, end, elapsed;

                start = new Date().getTime();
                document.location = uri;

                end = new Date().getTime();

                elapsed = (end - start);

                if (elapsed < 1) {
                    document.location = href;
                }
            }               
        })();
```

This code is based on Chase's answer at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675535/how-to-launch-apps-facebook-twitter-etc-from-mobile-browser-but-fall-back-to-h)

However the code is sometimes working sometimes not and could not figure out why?