# Open Facebook app with a link on a Website "fb://" url

Tags: facebook, deep-linking

Hi I'm trying to open the facebook app with a link from my webpage onto a specific page/profile which works great, "fb://profile/" (which is the same for both android and IOS but previously android required "fb://page/" which no longer works)

However if the phone does not have facebook installed this method does not work and tapping the link does nothing. Would anybody know if there is a way around this?

I'm kind of asking is there way in javascript if you can detect if facebook is installed and deep down i know the answer is no chance! Thanks.

Comment: i think a similar question to this which includes a possible solution (not attempted yet) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675535/