# How to launch system apps programmatically or how to filter out launchable system apps?

Tags: android, system, installed-applications, android-applicationinfo

I want to make  a list of installed and system applications. system applications means the pre-installed applications (applications which are installed at the time of manufacture).
For this i categorized all the apps using `(ApplicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0` - which are system apps and others are installed apps.
Now my problem is i want to launch these  apps on click of list items.But i could not launch system apps like Contacts,Dialer etc...

How to launch system apps programmatically or how to filter out launchable system apps?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382659/how-to-find-installed-applications-in-android?rq=1
it has a similar question

Comment: I got installed and system apps.I want  to know that is it possible to launch system apps using intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not found exact answer.But i think it will helpful

```
List<PackageInfo> list = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
for (PackageInfo pi : list) {
 try {
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = getPackageManager() .getApplicationInfo(pi.packageName, 0);
        //check whether the app is launchable or not
    if (packageManager .getLaunchIntentForPackage(appInfo.packageName) != null) {
     //check whether the app is an installed / system app
     if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
        //system apps.........
     } else {
        //installed apps............
     }
    }

   } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```